# how to kill a session that it exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

A user loged in site before. from another browser a user with same "UserName" logs in. Now I want to log out older user and replace new user. I can Recognize that a session with same "UserName" loged in, but I don't know how to kill it's session. 
Help me please.

Comment: Just why would you want to kill the other session?

Comment: its my sites plan. many websites do this plan. when a user logs in from a browser, user logs out from other browsers.

Comment: I'll check it out now... @Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your requirement, I think you want that two users with same username can't be logged in your application, and If your it happens then the user who logged in after the another one should continue and the older one get logged out.

For such requirement, you can generate the `Session Key` for each user who logged into the application and save it and check this value on each request. For this you can use `Application.BeginRequest` handler.

So basically what you are doing is generating the SessionKey for each login. So when another user logged in with same credential, you will generate the session key and after any request you will match this sessionKey against the currently saved session key for this username. if it is match then OK otherwise logged out this user.

Comment: Thanks; Yes, you've understood correctly my problem. I solved it by your idea, but a little different...